# jquery Window resize function revert

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, media-queries

If I use resize function how do I revert all the code back? I know I can write the reverse code for the same but want to know if there is any shortcut to do this as it is time consuming every time I write responsive media codes in jquery. see below code which I want to execute at window size of 320 to 767 and want to revert back to original code once window resized to more than 767 width.

```js
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this); //this = window
      if (win.width() <= 768) {
        $("#HEADER_BREADCRUMBS").hide();
    $('.standard_basket_line_total').next("div").append('<div id="new-block-2"></div>');

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".product_sizes_guide").hide();
      $("#divBasketListing").find("#divTotalText").parent().find(".standard_basket_image").remove();
      $("#divBasketListing").find("#divTotalText").parent().find(".standard_basket_text").remove();
      $("#divBasketListing").find("#divTotalText").parent().attr("id", "tsg-id-1");
    });
});
```

all the above code is for different div and different pages change class will be same as writing and reverse code for this. I want to know if there is something for example:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this); //this = window
      if (win.width() <= 767) { $("#3").hide();
$("#4").find("span").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-list"); }
else{
     $("#3").show();
$("#4").find("span").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-list");
    }
});
```

to be coded like the below code

```
<!--HTML Starts-->
<div id="3">Some text</div>
<div id="4"><span class="">Some more text</span></div>
<!--HTML ends-->

<!--Jquery Starts-->
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this); //this = window
      if (win.width() <= 767) { $("#3").hide();
$("#4").find("span").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-list"); }
else{ 
revert();
    }
});
<!--Jquery Ends-->
```

Comment: @mplungjan This is the jquery I have written and want to be reverted when window size gets more than 767px. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: You posted too much code. Now it is better. Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52836179/edit) and then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] - the shortcut is to change class

Comment: Also `var small = win.width() <= 767; $("#3").toggle(!small);` - ditto toggleClass

Comment: You are looking for toggling as @mplungjan hints to. jQuery's `.toggle()` and `.toggleClass()` are useful here. Do note that `Window.matchMedia()` is preferred because it makes CSS media queries and JS resize events work seamlessly whereas they don't when you just use `window.width` - mostly because of the scrollbar.

Comment: I do understand toggle would be helpful here but what if I am manipulating 100 elements at once lets say I am "changing width of 5 elements" "removing 3 elements" "hiding 8 elements" "adding 6 different id's to 6 different  elements" "removing 5 different div's and adding to them to different row's above". how can I do that in short without writing too much reverse code for the same?